# Count how many days pass between two periods

Tags: sas

is there a way to count how many days pass from a start-end to the next one? Let say:

> ```
>    ID            Start            End    
>  0001          22JAN2022       23JAN2022 
>  0001          26JAN2022       30JAN2022          
>  0001          03MAR2022       08MAR2022    
>  0001          09MAR2022       15MAR2022    
>  0001          17MAR2022       30MAR2022
> ```

desired output:

> ```
>    ID            Start            End           days 
>  0001          22JAN2022       23JAN2022         3
>  0001          26JAN2022       30JAN2022         4   
>  0001          03FEB2022       08MAR2022         1
>  0001          09MAR2022       15MAR2022         2
>  0001          17MAR2022       30MAR2022      .......
> ```

Comment: Just wondering: do you sometimes try to solve problems yourself first? It seems thar your first impulse is to drop your tasks on other people, so they do the work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I demonstrated this in another thread but there you go

```
data have;
input ID $ (Start End)(:date9.);
format Start End date9.;
datalines;
0001 22JAN2022 23JAN2022 
0001 26JAN2022 30JAN2022 
0001 03FEB2022 08MAR2022 
0001 09MAR2022 15MAR2022 
0001 17MAR2022 30MAR2022 
;

data want;
   set have;
   by ID;
   set have(firstobs = 2 rename = start = s keep = start)
       have(obs = 1 drop = _all_);
   if last.ID then s = .;
   days = s - end;
run;
```

Comment: Yes I see and thank you. It is something related to the previous question that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: I just changed the code in this way to let it to work and do the task I asked for: have(obs=2 drop=_all_);